# Distance between circular arc-like trajectory and straight line trajectory

Tags: geometry

An aircraft $ac_0$ flies a circular arc-like trajectory (radius $r$, start angle $\alpha_s$ end angle $\alpha_e$, circle center $c_c$ and speed $s_0$ in $\mathrm{radians/sec}$).

Another aircraft $ac_1$ flies a straight line trajectory (start position $p_1$, velocity vector $\vec{v_1}$). Both have constant speed.

I want to calculate at which time $t$ the distance between them has a certain value ($\mathrm{dist}$). How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried writing a formula that describes the distance between them as a function of $t$? One way is to write each aircraft's x-y coordinates as a function of $t$ and then use the Pythagorean Theorem to get the distance between the points.

Comment: @David K: yes I have, but had difficulty isolating the t (time) in the formula to calculate the time at which the distance equals dist.

Comment: The Cartesian coordinates for the two planes are $$\begin{cases}x_1(t) = x_c + r \cos(\alpha_s + s_0 t)\\y_1(t) = y_c + r \sin(\alpha_s + s_0 t)\end{cases}$$ $$\begin{cases}x_2(t) = x_p + x_v t\\y_2(t) = y_p + y_v\end{cases}$$but I don't think the underlying problem has a simple solution in the general case. For example, if $(x_p, y_p)$ is far from $(x_c,y_c)$, the Euclidean distance has many local minima, as the first plane flies in a circle.  That means that finding even a numerical solution is a bit tricky.

Comment: @Dennis It's usually advised to show all the work you did on the problem, even if it did not get you all the way to an answer. In the equations in the previous comment, it should say $y_v t$ rather than $y_v$, but after we fix that, are those the equations you used? Whatever you used, if you edit the question to include _your_ formulas then we'll all be starting with the same expressions that make sense to you.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am not looking for a minimum distance, but a certain specified distance dist. I guess that, given the equations from "Nominal Animal", I will have to solve: 
$dist = \sqrt ((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)$
The question is GIVEN a $dist$, how do I calculate the time $t$ at which this distance occurs?